# OTU table from phyloseq object can't be coerced into a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, phyloseq

I need to convert my OTU table from my phyloseq object into a data frame so that I can use it to run PICRUSt2, but `as.data.frame(physeq@otu_table)` won't make it a data frame. I tried `pie<-as.matrix(physeq@otu_table)` and when I say `is.matrix(pie) #it says TRUE`, but when I say `class(pie) #it says [1] "otu_table" attr(,"package") [1] "phyloseq"` It wont even pretend to be a data frame:

```
pie<-as.data.frame(physeq@otu_table)
is.data.frame(pie)
#FALSE
```

I can't just use my asv_mat from before I put it into the phyloseq object because I had to remove mitochondria and chloroplast from my phyloseq object. This will still be in asv_mat.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pie<-as.matrix(physeq@otu_table)
pie<-as.data.frame(pie)
```

making it a matrix, then saving as a dataframe and remembering to save over the original matrix as a data frame (i.e. `pie<-as.data.frame(pie)` rather than just `as.data.frame(pie)`) worked.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I don't have enough information to properly help you, but have you ever tried to use as_tibble() from the tidyverse package, instead of as_dataframe() ?